# How can I scrape HTML with Nokogiri without tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I need to parse a local HTML file using Nokogiri, but the HTML doesn't have any `<div>`s with classes. It starts with text.

This is the HTML:

```
high prices in <a href="Example 1">Example 1</a><br>
low prices in <a href="Example 2">Example 2</a><br>
```

In this case I just need to get "high" and "low", and "example 1", and "example 2".

How can I get the text, with no elements? From the tutorials I saw, it needs some `<div class= ...>` to get the text.

```
doc.xpath('//a/@href').each do |node|   #get performance indicators
      link = node.text

      @test << Entry2.new(link)

    end

    @title = doc.xpath('//p').text.scan(/^(high|low)/)
```

My view:

```
   <% @test.each do |entry| %>


    <p>  <%= entry.link %></p>

<% end %>


<% @title.each do |f| %>
    <p>  <%= f %></p>


<% end %>
```

And the output is like this:

```
Example 1Example 2

[["high"], ["low"]]
```

It's listing all at the same time instead of one by one. How can I change my Nokogiri code to look like this in the output?

```
high prices in Example 1
low prices in Example 2
```

Comment: "From the tutorials I saw, it needs some <div class= ...> to get the text." Then you missed the point of the tutorials. You *can* use parameters inside tags to search. Nokogiri also has CSS shortcuts that make it easier to search for `class` and `id` parameters. The idea is you search for tags, or portions of tags. With XPath you can dive in deeper, into the text nodes. CSS is somewhat limited that way but can it too. Usually we look for way-points in the HTML that help us locate the desired content. Your example is pretty limited; Is that the entire HTML or just the immediate text?

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". There's a lot of missing code in your question. Please create a minimal example that demonstrates the problem and will run.

Comment: You didn't provide enough HTML. Certainly the text you are referring to is in _some sort_ of container element. It doesn't have to be a `div`.

Answer (score 3):

Well, Nokogiri will wrap that string in an implicit `<html><body><p>...` so the text will be in a single `<p>`

So yes, you will be able to get the links in a structured form with:

```
doc.xpath "//a"
```

The "high" and "low" strings will be in a single blob of text. You will probably need to pull them out with some regex which will depend a lot on your requirements and data, but here's the regex for what you're showing and asking for:

```
doc.xpath('//p').text.scan(/^(high|low)/)
```

I can't be sure how helpful that will specifically be with your actual requirements, but hopefully it gives you a direction to take.

Comment: thanks! now I can get the examples and the high/low part. But it's listing all at the same time, I edited my question with some code based on what you said, can you help me in listing one by one?

Comment: You're doing `doc.xpath('//p').each` which suggests that you've totally ignored what I said in my first paragraph, **there's only going to be one `<p>`**.

Comment: I edited again, but how can I put the view like the end of the question

Comment: Open a `rails console` type the code you have to initialize `doc` and then type `doc.xpath('//p').text.scan(/^(high|low)/)` and see what's returned. Although I'd be really worried that you have a Rails view that has `<p>`s in it but the output has none!

Comment: I said my output was like this: Example 1Example 2

[["high"], ["low"]]